# Alternate to setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, thread_id, priority)

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

*Given* - Thread id of a thread.
*Requirement* - Set Linux priority of the thread id.
*Constraint* - Cant use setpriority()

I have tried to use below

**pthread_setschedprio**(pthread_t thread, int prio);
**pthread_setschedparam**(pthread_t thread, int policy,
                          const struct sched_param *param);

Both the above APIs use pthread_t as an argument. I am not able to construct (typecast) pthread_t from thread id. I understand converting this is not possible due to different types.

Is there a way to still accomplish this ?

Comment: From where do you get the thread ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some aspects of the `pthread_setschedprio` interface are available for plain thread IDs with the `sched_setparam` function (declared in `<thread.h>`).  The [`sched_setparam` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setparam.2.html) says that the process is affected (which is the POSIX-mandated behavior), but on Linux, [it's actually the thread of that ID](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14829).

Keep in mind that calling `sched_setparam` directly may break the behavior expected from PI mutexes and other synchronization primitives because the direct call does not perform the additional bookkeeping performed by the `pthread_`* functions.

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected. Missed the API while googling.